# Random Variables Question

Tags: statistics

I have begun learning Statistics and I'd just like to ask a few questions and check that I've understood everything quickly.

So, I've been introduced to 'Random Variables' $X$ as mappings from the sample space $S$ of a by chance experiment to the real number line $\mathbb{R}$. $$ X:S \to \mathbb{R} $$

**Question 1:** Would the following be a valid discrete random variables? Let $Y$ be the discrete random variable that maps students from a classroom to their heights in cm rounded to the nearest integer. I doubt the legitimacy of this drv because it does not vary by chance, heights stay the same.

**Question 2:** Are Discrete random variables mappings from the sample space to the set of integers or are they defined as only taking a countable/finite number of outcomes? So, If we take part in the random experiment of rolling a dice and assigned the set of outcomes $ \begin{Bmatrix} 1,2,3,4,5,6 \end{Bmatrix} $ to their corresponding numerical integer values. This Random variables takes 6 outcomes, so would it be a discrete random variable?

Comment: In question 1, the issue is not the mapping - but rather a proper sample space has not been defined, which in turn requires a "random experiment" to be defined. Suppose you defined the random experiment to be selecting a student at random from the classroom. Then consider using your definition of $Y$ on the resulting sample space from the defined random experiment.

Comment: @Just_to_Answer Thanks, understood!

Comment: @Just_to_Answer I did some more work on this topic yesterday and it seems my definition of a discrete random variable was somewhat incorrect. Apparently, for a random variable to be a discrete random variable it must satisfy two conditions. 1: The sample space must have a finite number of outcomes or a 'countably infinite number of outcomes'. Could you explain what countably infinite number of outcomes means?

Comment: Please see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CountablyInfinite.html for example.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:**:  $Y$ is not a discrete random variable because each has a fixed value.  (Think of the prototypical discrete random variable being the output of a coin toss.)

**Question 2:** Yes, a discrete random variable can have 6 or indeed any such number of outputs.

Comment: So it's not mappings from the sample space to the set of integers